# Passing implicit function pointers

Tags: c++, c++98

In some C++ 98 code (meaning no, using `std::function` is not an option), I found the following construct:

```
class someClass
{
public:
    typedef void callback();

    void setCallback(callback c)
    {
        mCallback = c;
    }

    void callCallback()
    {
        if (mCallback)
            mCallback();
    }
private:
    callback *mCallback;
};
```

This confused me. I am used to passing callback functions as a function pointer, so I would expect `setCallback` to take `(*callback)()` as argument.

However, the above code seems to work, and compiles without any (related) warnings.

Could someone tell me what is happening here? Is my callback function implicitly passed as a function pointer? Is it a good idea to use this instead of function pointers?

The only thing I could find is that this construction results in "parameter-declaration-clause" ambiguity (C++ 98 [8.3p7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf#page=166)). Is this the only downside? Are there any benefits?

Comment: a function type is adjusted to a pointer to function type in a parameter declaration

Comment: When a function type is used as a function parameter type, it is adjusted to pointer-to-function type, so `setCallback` could equally have been declared as `void setCallback(callback * c)`. (Function types and array types are very similar in this and related regards.)

Comment: Is there any reference to this in the spec? As far as I know, this does not exists in C...

Comment: It's 8.3.5/5 in C++ (WD), and it's 6.7.6.3/8 in C11.

Comment: "After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”, respectively". Thanks.

Comment: So, does anyone know if this has any advantages over using function pointers?

Comment: @Bitbored less typing when instantiating a function template, say `foo<void()>(bar)` instead of `foo<void(*)()>(bar)`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to arrays, parameters of function type declare, in fact, a pointer to that type.